# Google Chrome Extension, Property Collector and URL Reconstruct

Tags: google-chrome-extension

New to Chrome programming, but am more or less familiar with Javascript.

Goal:

A Chrome add-on that will allow me to:

1) Right-click on an link

2) then add a some more characters to that link

3) then reload the page with the new constructed URL.

EX:

A. Object has a link : www.address.com/34922

B. User righ-clicks on that object (Chrome's menu appears [which I know how to mod]), a menu option appears 'reconstruct rul.'

C. The add-on adds '/subfolderA' to the above mentioned url.

D. Page reloads with the following URL: www.address.com/34922/subfolderA

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`chrome.contextMenus`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html) API, more specifically the [`create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create) method.

```
// Add this to the background page
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: 'Open this link plus /subfolderA',
    contexts: ['link'],
    onclick: function(info, tab) {
        var linkUrl = info.linkUrl;
        // Some logic, eg adding a fragment:
        linkUrl += '/subfolderA';
        // Replace URL on current tab
        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: linkUrl});
    },
    // The following array should consist of valid match patterns
    //  This context menu item will only be visible on matching links
    targetUrlPatterns: ['http://adress.com/*']
});
```

### Relevant documentation

Used methods:

- [`chrome.contextMenus`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html) API

  - [`chrome.tabs.create(<object createProperties>)`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create)
  - The [onClickData](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/contextMenus.html#type-OnClickData) type. This is just a plain JavaScript object. However, Chrome *will* validate this object, and throw an error when an unknown format (e.g. wrong property) is used.
- [`chrome.tabs`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) API

  - [`chrome.tabs.update(<integer tabId>, <object updateProperties>)`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update)

Further reading:

- [Background pages](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/background_pages.html)
- [Manifest file](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html)
- [Match patterns](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html)

Comment: New to the board, did not know that.. Done.